# Is it possible to return a formula from a function?

Tags: r

I'm a lazy guy so I don't want to type the same codes again and again (not even copy and paste :P). I'm wondering if it's possible to write a function that will return some text strings **as formula**, so next time, when I want to use this pack of commends, I can just call the function and that whole piece of codes will be pasted in automatically.

For example, this time, I'm using `ggplot2` to produce some box plots and I want to do some customizations to my plot. So I have

```
ggplot(abc, aes(group, abcabc))+geom_boxplot(aes(fill=group)) + 
geom_hline(yintercept=0, color="grey") +
theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill = "white")) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "white"))
```

You can see the last two lines of codes are just doing some formatting setup. I can use these two lines of codes every time when I want to generate a boxplot in this format in the future. If I can write a function that can return these two lines of codes as formula, I can just use that function as some sort of themes in `ggplot` in the future. So I tried to write a function like this:

```
box.format<-function(){
            return(as.formula('theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill = "white")) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "white"))'))
}
```

However, I got a message like this:

> Error: Don't know how to add scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "white")) to a theme object

Does anyone know how to fix this error or are there any other ways to do so?

Comment: I thought that was the point of using themes, so you can set those components....

Comment: @AnandaMahto Do you mean `ggthemes` package or something else? In this case, I was just trying to find out a way to build some customized themes so I can reuse them latter. I was trying to find something online but I couldn't find any.... If you can guide me to some places, that will be the best!

Comment: I am not much of a "ggplot2" user, but I would start [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html).

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks! I actually the answer at the very end of that page. You can actually write a function to save customized themes and use it later by wrapping the codes with `theme`. For example, `a<-function(){theme(...........................)}`

Comment: What you are describing is *not* a formula in R. Formulas are in the form `y~x`. `ggplot` uses `+` for composition and that's just a regular function.

Comment: @MrFlick Ah, you got the point! Thank you for letting me know that

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may try closure. Below is a quick trial although it is not tested fully. Ideally you should be able to create your own function factory with closures.

```
mygg <- function(...) {
  function(data, x, y) {
    ggplot(data, aes(x, y))+geom_boxplot(aes(fill=x)) + 
      geom_hline(yintercept=0, color=color_param) +
      theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill = back_param)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c(scale_param_x, scala_param_y))    
  }
}

gg <- mygg(color_param = "grey", back_param = "white", scale_param_x = "white", scale_param_y = "white")
gg
function(data, x, y) {
  ggplot(data, aes(x, y))+geom_boxplot(aes(fill=x)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=0, color=color_param) +
    theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill = back_param)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(scale_param_x, scala_param_y))    
}
<environment: 0x0000000018d7cea0>
```